# Decidability/undecidability of the feasibility of optimization problems

Tags: logic, nonlinear-optimization, decidability

I am building on top of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133951/is-the-feasibility-of-a-system-of-non-convex-quadratic-equations-and-inequations) on MathOverflow.

The conclusion was that feasibility is decidable. Can one give a direct proof **without** using heavy machinery like Tarski's theorem?

I do not quite understand decidability/undecidability or Tarski's theorem well. However, my intuition tells me that since the sets in question are compact and the functions in question are continuous, some direct proof should be possible for feasibility questions of this kind. Or is what is happening here much deeper than mere compactness and continuity? (Imprecise statement -- reminds me that when sinusoidal functions are included in a theory, decidability vanishes).

Part of the reason why I ask this question is for understanding. The other is that what happens if exponential function is included in the optimization problem? Decidability of the theory of $(R;+,-, \times, <, =, \exp,0,1)$ requires Schanuel's conjecture; however if we pose an optimization problem with the exponential function on compact sets, can one prove decidability of feasibility directly without Schanuel's conjecture?

Comment: Are you acquainted with [MetiTarski](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith/index.html)?

Comment: Rodrigo de Azevedo -- The optimization problem on top of which I'm building (the link https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133951/is-the-feasibility-of-a-system-of-non-convex-quadratic-equations-and-inequations) of are of the kind you mention in your comment, ``Which optimization ....'' So, restrict to the first part of the question: can feasibility be proved without resorting to Tarski's theorem for the question asked in this link?

Comment: How about [cylindrical algebraic decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition) (CAD)?

Comment: Rodrigo -- I will look into CAD and MetiTarski. Thanks so much for all your time.

Comment: On practical quantifier elimination for engineering applications, you may want to take a look at [Verification and Synthesis Using Real Quantifier Elimination](http://www.csl.sri.com/users/tiwari/papers/issac2011.pdf) (2011) [pdf].

Comment: Your question is far from clear. What do you want a direct proof of? (By the way, CAD is an optimised approach to Tarski's theorem and MetiTarski is an automated proof finder that combines CAD with traditional first-order resolution theorem-proving. I don't think the pointers to these approaches will help you if you are concerned with general theory rather than trying to determine feasibility of specifc problems.)

Comment: Hi Rob, by direct proof I mean using only facts about compactness (the usual real analysis compactness: every open cover has a finite sub-cover) of spaces, continuous (and differentiable) functions on these sets. What is considered basic real analysis (include complex, if it helps), let us say.